# Working with chars and only solution I've found is to static_cast twice. Is there a way around this?

Tags: c++, char

This code seems a bit ridiculous, but it's the only way I found to deal with my problem...

```
char word[10];
cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(word[i]));
```

This is my way of cout-ing a char as a hex value (including signed chars). It seems to work great (to my knowledge), but I feel it's a very stupid way to do it.
I should add, I'm reading a file, that's why my data type is char initially.

Comment: Woops! Sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: cout << std::hex << int(word[i]);   //added as a comment

Comment: From what you have, that appears to be the right way to do it and still get the standard-blessed promotion and conversion you desire.

Comment: Why is this so hard? This one works: `(word[i] & 255)` But a direct cast to `unsigned char` doesn't work, I thought it should be the same.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani `word[i] & 255` is an `int` result. A direct cast to `unsigned char` obviously isn't. [example here](http://ideone.com/zjG9NL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it the right way, although using `int` would work as well as `unsigned int`.  You could make a function or a functor if you'll be doing this in several places, e.g.:

```
int char_to_int(char ch)
{ 
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(ch);
}

// ...
 cout << hex << char_to_int(word[i]);
```

---

As noted in comments, another option is `word[i] & 0xFF` with no casting. This is actually implementation-defined but most likely will give the intended result.  But again, if you will be doing this in several places I would suggest wrapping it up in a function so that it is more obvious what is going on.

Comment: Huh. Well, I'm glad I did it correctly. I felt like it was a case where I hadn't learned a trick yet. Thanks.